# How to add class to element based off a form input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

How can I add the highlight class (to indicate which price break the customer is qualified for) to the list item based on the quantity entered? onchange?

```
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item highlight">Less than 10 <span class="pull-right">$34.50</span></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">10 to 40 <span class="pull-right">$34.50</span></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">40+ <span class="pull-right">$34.50</span></li>
    </ul>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Quantity">
```

Comment: `onchange` is a good place to start.. I suggest giving it a shot, then let us know what you tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the quantity to the `li` elements somehow (I suggest `id="lt10"`, `id="10-40"` and `id="40plus"`, then create some rules in your input's `change` callback to determine which li to highlight.

Also, give your input an id and/or name.

```
-- html:
...
<input type="text" id="qty" placeholder="Quantity">

-- jquery:

$('#qty').change(function() {
    var quantity = parseInt( $(this).val() );

    // reset highlight classes for the elements
    $('.list-group li').removeClass('highlight');

    // apply new highlight classes
    if( quantity < 10 )
        $('li#lt10').addClass('highlight');
    else if( quantity >= 10 && quantity <= 40 )
        $('li#10-40').addClass('highlight');
    else if( quantity > 40 )
        $('li#40plus').addClass('highlight');
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me as long as I load the jquery snippet after the input element. Thank you!